# Android DOM parsing from URL

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

I am creating an android app (using android studio) which uses live data from the link:
http://transportapi.com/v3/uk/public/journey/from/Ladbroke%20Grove/to/Turnham%20Green.xml?api_key=a0d27caa983732936f45a891ebca6452&app_id=dc5f42ae&region=tfl

The information is in the form of XML, meaning I need to parse it into my application using a DOM parser. However, an error seems to occur when the code gets to this point:

```
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
```

My program isn't showing any errors when I run it, it simply throws an error every time it reaches this point on the code. This results in 'not reading' being printed out in the textView (declared as tv1 in the code).

I understand there are lots of questions on here regarding parsing XML from a URL on android, however none of them seem to help my situation! If anyone has any ideas what I have done wrong they would be much appreciated.

```
    try {

        URL url = new URL("http://transportapi.com/v3/uk/public/journey/from/Ladbroke%20Grove/to/Turnham%20Green.xml?api_key=a0d27caa983732936f45a891ebca6452&app_id=dc5f42ae&region=tfl");


        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("route");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                tv1.setText(tv1.getText() + "Duration of route " + ": " + getValue("duration", eElement) + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        tv1.setText("not reading");
    }



      private static String getValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
           NodeList nlList =  eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();
              Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
              return nValue.getNodeValue();
}
```

}

Comment: so what does `e.printStackTrace();`print?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following for xml parsing:
https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/samples/training/network-usage/src/com/example/android/networkusage/StackOverflowXmlParser.java?repo=platform--development&r=99ca344b233f9419bf4cefc69997d54fc419b326

```
   public class StackOverflowXmlParser {
private static final String ns = null;

// We don't use namespaces

public List<Entry> parse(InputStream in) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    try {
        XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(in, null);
        parser.nextTag();
        return readFeed(parser);
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}

private List<Entry> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "feed");
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        // Starts by looking for the entry tag
        if (name.equals("entry")) {
            entries.add(readEntry(parser));
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return entries;
}

// This class represents a single entry (post) in the XML feed.
// It includes the data members "title," "link," and "summary."
public static class Entry {
    public final String title;
    public final String link;
    public final String summary;

    private Entry(String title, String summary, String link) {
        this.title = title;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.link = link;
    }
}

// Parses the contents of an entry. If it encounters a title, summary, or link tag, hands them
// off
// to their respective &quot;read&quot; methods for processing. Otherwise, skips the tag.
private Entry readEntry(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "entry");
    String title = null;
    String summary = null;
    String link = null;
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        if (name.equals("title")) {
            title = readTitle(parser);
        } else if (name.equals("summary")) {
            summary = readSummary(parser);
        } else if (name.equals("link")) {
            link = readLink(parser);
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return new Entry(title, summary, link);
}

// Processes title tags in the feed.
private String readTitle(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "title");
    String title = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "title");
    return title;
}

// Processes link tags in the feed.
private String readLink(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    String link = "";
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "link");
    String tag = parser.getName();
    String relType = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "rel");
    if (tag.equals("link")) {
        if (relType.equals("alternate")) {
            link = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "href");
            parser.nextTag();
        }
    }
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "link");
    return link;
}

// Processes summary tags in the feed.
private String readSummary(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "summary");
    String summary = readText(parser);
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "summary");
    return summary;
}

// For the tags title and summary, extracts their text values.
private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    String result = "";
    if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
        result = parser.getText();
        parser.nextTag();
    }
    return result;
}

// Skips tags the parser isn't interested in. Uses depth to handle nested tags. i.e.,
// if the next tag after a START_TAG isn't a matching END_TAG, it keeps going until it
// finds the matching END_TAG (as indicated by the value of "depth" being 0).
private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    int depth = 1;
    while (depth != 0) {
        switch (parser.next()) {
        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                depth--;
                break;
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                depth++;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}